# Do I use a 5V 2A or 3A DC adapter to power my 2m (6.5ft) WS2801 LED strip?

Tags: led, power, current, adapter

(Please excuse me if my English is bad)

I recently purchased a 5m LED strip, but I only need to power approximately 2m (6.5ft) of the 5050 RGB LED WS2801 strip, but I'm afraid that a DC power adapter with 2A may not provide enough current, or a 3A or more may damage the LEDs, what do you think I should go for?

Here's a few specs about the 5m LED strip:

Input voltage: DC5V
Current: 3.2A
LED Qty: 32 per meter
Power(W/M):7.68W/M

Comment: Why do you think the leds will be damaged when u provide 3A current? And the power consumption is based on what? Because when you want white light is takes more current then when you just want red light.

Comment: You need a 3A supply. Higher will not hurt. See my modified answer.

Comment: +1 Why was this downvoted. It's effectively a design question - even though the power supply that answers the design need will usually be purchased. Most of the components people use are also purchased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current ability of supply should be equal or greater than current required.
A supply able to supply more than required will do no harm.
As I = V/R , current is provided "on demand". The supply supplies what is needed, not more.

For reasons explained below, a 3A supply is just about right for your 2m strip.
A 2A supply is underrated and a >3A supply will do no harm.

In the calculations below I have used the figures to the number of places specified and not rounded the results in calculations. In practice the values in the specification sheet will be approximate and will vary between samples. A variation of +/- 5% in currents would be good, +/- 10% not surprising and > 10% not unknown.
Such variations will usually not matter. Occasionally they will.
It pays tp provide somewhat more power supply capacity than required as the voltage may "sag" somewhat when loaded to the limit. Some supplies will get excessively hot when at or slightly above their specified ratings BUT these are liable to also have other problems - such as being death traps occasionally. A good 3A supply from a competent manufacturer will usually give you 10% + above the rated value without demur.

---

**Your specifications are inconsistent**
Current = Power/Volts.  or I = P/V
If the strip was 7.68 W/m as claimed then at 1m the current would be
I = P/V = 7.68/5 = 1.556A and 5m = 7.78A

**Suspect values:**

If I = 3.2A (another of your specs) then with 32 LED/s each LED would draw 3.2A/32 = 100 mA. This is conceivable with all 3 LEDs operating - some suppliers say 60 mA = 20 mA per LED colour and 100 mA = 33 mA per LED colour. It is usual but not certain to rate LEDs of this size at 20 mA / LED colour - but it is possible to be higher.

At 3.2A/metre 1m will take 5V x 3.2A = 16W
and 5m will take 5 x 16W = 80W
which seems 'rather high' [tm].

**Probable correct values:**

If we instead use the quoted 7.68W/m
I/m = P/V = 7.68/5 = 1.536A
As there are 32 LEDS/m this means
each LED takes 1.5436/32  = 48 mA/LED
or 16 mA per LED segment.
This sounds closer to likely reality (but may not be).

Assume the 3.2A figures is correct. Then:

V = 5V
I per m = 1.536A
I per 5m = 7.68A <- explains the 7.68 figure in the data.
P per m = 7.68W
P per 5m = 38.4 W

2m requires 2 x 1.536 = 3.072A

ie a 3A supply is about right.

---

M for metre should be m as Mr Metre did not exist.

Comment: I doubt that the current for the whole 5m would be 3.2A....

Comment: The ws 2801 strips are smart, chain addressed rgb leds, that run on 5V. they are not 12V  dumb led strips.

Comment: @Passerby Ta thankee kindy sir - right you be then, I see. I have been suitably educated and added another [**pretty pebble**](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Isaac_Newton) to my collection. (I'm never going to acquire but a tiny fraction of what Newton managed, alas). Answer corrected accordingly. Problem was that the 3.2A in the spec seem entirely spurious and does not seem to correspond to any other value.

Comment: Thank you Russell for your complete and clear answer, I have learned a lot through your explanations and calculations.

Answer (score 1):

The "current" value on the power supply is the maximum current the supply can deliver without being damaged or running into protection.
So there is no need to fear that a power supply with a high "current" rating damages your LED strip.

But like Russell already stated, the values you provide are not consistent. On the one hand you state your strip will consume 3.2 A at 5 Volts, but on the other hand it consumes 7.68W/m, or 38,4 Watts for 5 Meters.

Because Power is the product of voltage and current (P=U*I), this means the current will be:

> I = P/U = 38,4 Watts / 5 Volts =  7,68 A

Check what is right and choose a power supply that will be able to provide at least the maximum amount of current your LED strip will consume (so even the 3 A supply is undersized).

Comment: Thank you bns for your clear answer. I didn't know that the power supply would only provide the current the LEDs will need. I also think the specs provided by the seller's website are wrong (P=7,26W/m & I=3,2A for 5m strip). I'm going to try at first a power supply with 3A.